# XML Parsing with NSXMLParser - I need code review

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I just need confirmation that I am doing XML parsing right. Am I doing something wrong here:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate> 
{   
    NSXMLParser *parser;    
    NSMutableArray *ordersList; 

    BOOL orderIdFound;
    BOOL itemNameFound;
    BOOL priceFound;
    BOOL orderDateFound;
    BOOL deliveryDateFound;

    Order *orderObject;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *ordersList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSXMLParser *parser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Order *orderObject;

@end


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize ordersList;
@synthesize parser;
@synthesize orderObject;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ordersList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // Reading local XML file
    NSString *xmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"orders" ofType:@"xml"];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [parser parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{       
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"OrderId"])
    {           
        orderIdFound = YES;
        if(orderObject == nil)
        {
            orderObject = [[Order alloc]init];
        }
        else 
        {
            [ordersList addObject:orderObject];

            [orderObject release];
            orderObject = nil;
            orderObject = [[Order alloc]init];
        }
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ItemName"])
    {
        itemNameFound = YES;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Price"])
    {
        priceFound = YES;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"OrderDate"])
    {
        orderDateFound = YES;   
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"DeliveryDate"])
    {
        deliveryDateFound = YES;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{    
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"OrderId"])
    {
        orderIdFound = NO;      
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"ItemName"])
    {
        itemNameFound = NO;     
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Price"])
    {
        priceFound = NO;        
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"OrderDate"])
    {
        orderDateFound = NO;        
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"DeliveryDate"])
    {
        deliveryDateFound = NO;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if(orderIdFound == YES)
    {
        orderObject.OrderId = [string integerValue];
        NSLog(@"orderId :: %i", orderObject.OrderId);

    }
    if(itemNameFound == YES)
    {       
        orderObject.ItemName = string;
        NSLog(@"itemName :: %@", orderObject.ItemName);
    }
    if(priceFound == YES)
    {       
        orderObject.Price = [string integerValue];
        NSLog(@"price :: %i", orderObject.Price);
    }
    if(orderDateFound == YES)
    {       
        orderObject.OrderDate = string;
        NSLog(@"orderDate :: %@", orderObject.OrderDate);
    }
    if(deliveryDateFound == YES)
    {       
        orderObject.DeliveryDate = string;
        NSLog(@"deliveryDate :: %@", orderObject.DeliveryDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a problem when you run the code? Does it seem to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks generally ok, except that you're leaking memory. Any calls to alloc, new, copy or retain need to balanced with a release (e.g. in dealloc).

Also, I would suggest not doing XML parsing in a view controller. XML parsing is a seperate concern and is suitable for factoring out into a seperate class.

Comment: You forgot calls to retain need releasing too.

Comment: Thanks, I will release parser and other objects in dealloc. Generally I was most concern about this code "if(orderObject == nil)
        {
            orderObject = [[Order alloc]init];
        }
        else 
        {
            [ordersList addObject:orderObject];

            [orderObject release];
            orderObject = nil;
            orderObject = [[Order alloc]init];
        }"
And I will move this to separate class :) Thanks

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you're trying to do. What format is the XML? From your parser, it looks a bit unstructured. Can you post a sample of the XML?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orders>
 <Order>
  <OrderId>1</OrderId>
  <ItemName>Hammer</ItemName>
  <Price>5</Price>
  <OrderDate>24/02/2010</OrderDate>
  <DeliveryDate>28/02/2010</DeliveryDate>
  <Driver>
          <DriverId>11</DriverId>
   <DriverName>Julia</DriverName>
  </Driver>
 </Order>
...

Comment: Btw, rather than doing "[orderObject release]; orderObject = nil;" instead you can do "self.orderObject = nil;" (because the property is retained). Much neater.

Comment: Ah excellent, that XML is more structured than I thought. Ok, to make your code less awkward, watch out in didStartElement for the "Order" element, and in didEndElement watch out for the same element ending, and in those places manage your creation etc. of the orderObject. Will make things simpler.